# Trigger not working after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this trigger:

```
delimiter //
create trigger nuevaVenta
after insert on medapp.Compra
for each row
begin
    if new.idProducto = Productos_Farmaceuticos.idProducto then
        update medapp.Productos_Farmaceuticos
        set Productos_Farmaceuticos.inventario = 
            Productos_Farmaceuticos.inventario - new.cantProduct;
    end if;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

but when I try to make an insert on Compra I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'Productos_Farmaceuticos' in field list
```

here is the insert I tried to perform:

```
INSERT INTO medapp.Compra (idProducto,idPaciente,fecha,cantProduct) values ('001','002','2013-11-15','7');
```

and my tables:

```
Compra (idPaciente, idProducto, fecha, cantProduct)
Productos_Farmaceuticos (idProducto, nombreProduct, precioProduct, puntoReorden, inventario)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
delimiter //
create trigger nuevaVenta
after insert on Compra
for each row
begin
    update Productos_Farmaceuticos
       set inventario = invetario - new.cantProduct
     where idProducto = new.idProducto;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: it now gives me "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'invetario' in 'field list'"

Comment: Do you have `Productos_Farmaceuticos` table in medapp schema (db)?

Comment: made an error while copying the error, and yes, I do have it. The correct error code was "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'invetario' in 'field list'"

Comment: found the error, your query works it only had an small spelling error (invetario instead of inventario), also mine had the same error. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @arturojain Great! You're quite welcome. Good luck :)